# How to create a repeating Events like google gmail in php?

Tags: php, events, drupal, drupal-7

I want to create repeating Events like gmail. IF any idea, Please let me know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can use Date/Calendar recursion library for PHP 5.2+ by Thomas Planer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup/install the [Date module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) on your site.  Then, in the Event content type, configure your event date field with the repeat option enabled (see screenshot in [Lullabot's blog post about the date module](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/whats-new-in-date-and-calendar-for-drupal-7))

Also, here are a few considerations about dates during your Event content type and views setup process:

- Once you configure the date field and add event content with those fields defined, you won't be able to modify the field settings to a more restrictive state. (For example, if you enable repeat and then decide to disable repeat).  A work around for this is to create a new date field with desired settings, use views bulk operations to copy the data from obsolete date field to new date field, then delete obsolete date field.)
- When working with repeating or ongoing events, you'll need to determine how you want them to appear in chronological event listing views.  (For example, ongoing events may wind up showing at top of list if your sort is based only on start date.  If your view is limited to very few listings/results, and all your events repeat- make sure there's enough variety of events to avoid showing the same repeating event back to back in the view. You may want to consider showing only distinct results in the view.)
- When working with repeating dates, do the times also repeat?  If not, you may want to also install the [Node Clone module](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) and configure so content managers can copy event nodes and edit/modify times.
- If showing times, do you need to show timezones associated with them?